# How to keep one image on a certain part of a responsive background image, as the webpage resizes?

Tags: html, css, responsive, responsive-images

For example, if I have a background image of a cyclone and it's responsive/resizes with the window and covers the whole web page (background-size: cover), but the eye of the cyclone isn't in the center of the webpage but say slightly more to the right and I wanted another image, say a picture of an apple, to always cover the eye of the cyclone, no matter what size the window is, what could I do?

I've tried playing around with the margin percentages, the image of the apple is also responsive and shrinks with the background image to cover the eye of the cyclone but the images always tend to move out of sync just before I've dragged the window to it's smallest size.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS background size property can have value of cover. The cover value tells the browser to automatically and proportionally scale the background images width and height so that they are always equal to or greater than the viewports
width/height.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Img tag use height i and width in pixel then change in CSS
then output will show properly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Check the Multiple Backgrounds CSS feature which will achieve your request: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_backgrounds.asp

[image]

Comment: This is not quite a link-only answer but it's close. Please add text to your question that makes your question useful even if the link goes dead.